# show all tabs with scrolling option (on screen there should be only 4 tabs)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios6, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am newbie for iOS development. What I have done so far is as below.

1. Created New Project
2. Removed all controller and added View Controller.
3. Dragged `ScrollView` in `ViewController`
4. Dragged `Tab Bar` in `ScrollView`
5. Dragged 7 `Tab Bar Item` in `Tab Bar`.

Now when I execute this project, I have all 7 tabs on screen which is not looking good. So what I am planning is display only 4 tab at first and if user scroll it horizontally, user can scroll and see rest  tabs.

**So, what I want to achieve is programmatically set some parameter in `ScrollView` that it will display only first 4 options only.**

Any idea/ suggestion on this to be done?

Comment: @HDdeveloper : I have not used code anywhere... its just dragging the items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT :

I think this one may be even more adapted to the situation. Contrary to KLHorizontalSelect, it's kind of old (no commit on the master branch for a year ?) and I have no experience with it, but it may solve your problem : [InfiniTabBar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/infinitabbar).

The description is short :

> A scrolling tab bar with space for infinite items

---

Maybe you can take a look at this control : [KLHorizontalSelect](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/klhorizontalselect).

Here's how it looks like :

[image]

I don't think it **looks** exactly as you want, but I think it **works** almost as what you're expecting. Maybe you can work on the design ?

Comment: No problem. Which one did you choose ? Always remember that 99% of the time, someone has already done what you're trying to do. So always google your search first and you'll most likely find something useful. Remember the site CocoaControls, you'll find a lot of custom made controls over there, and they add new ones every day.

Comment: I choosed above image... hope I will use this whenever needed... I will make it clear...

Comment: can you take a look at [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775745/how-to-select-viewcontroller-based-on-selection-done)

Answer (score 0):

You have no code used so far, but you'll absolutely have to do that to achieve this. I'll get you started:

Create a scrollview at the bottom of your viewcontroller. Create UIViews on it and make them have a width of 640 (iPhone Retina screen width). You can put a image and a title on the UIView and make them function as a button. Set the content size to 640/4 *7 and there you go. You can give the background of the scrollview the same image as the UITabBar, but you'll need [this](http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-6-gui-psd-iphone-5/).

This snippet might help you:

```
for (int i = 0; i<7; i++){
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 + 50*i,0, 50,50);
    [scrollView addSubview:view];
}
```

You'll have to multiply the x origin with the width of the UIViews (plus some margin) to make sure they aren't all on the same spot.