# Tabbarcontroller with more than 5 items scrolling the items in iphone?

Tags: ios

I have an Iphone application in which i need to have a tabbarcontroller in which it i need 6 tab bar items, which are scrollable inside that tabbar controller.

I don't want to implement the mechanism of more item in that, so that i tried infinitabbar, jsscrollingtbabar, but in which all the tab bar itself is scrolling

But i need the tab bar to stay fixed and scroll the items inside it, or having a tab bar which is having a length of about 390 pixels. So that we can scroll it to there.

Comment: Check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743777/show-all-tabs-with-scrolling-option-on-screen-there-should-be-only-4-tabs

Comment: Also looks like a good plugin to support this -> https://github.com/jain-mohit/CustomTabBar