# iOS customized tabview bar with different size icons

Tags: ios, tabview

Is there a way to customize the bottom tabview buttons to have different sizes and even shape. Something like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever made this? if yes, which approach did you follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `UITabBar` to have a different shape or size, unfortunately, you won't be able to change it even by subclassing `UITabBar`.

To get started, you'll want to take a look at subclassing another type of `UIView` -- either vanilla `UIView` or `UIImageView`, add icons to them, and configure touch events to make them do what you want.

Here's some helpful resources for you to get started:

- [How Can I Create My Own UITabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020108/how-can-i-create-my-own-uitabbar)
- [Making a Thinner UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563701/making-a-thinner-uitabbar)